# How to Enable Magento 2.4 modules because of the following constraints

Tags: magento, magento2

As I am new to Magento 2.4, I just tried to upgrade M2.3 to M 2.4 by disabling Elasticsearch

php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}

I have successfully updated Magento to 2.4 now my products catalog is not visible.

**We can't find products matching the selection.**

Now I tried to enable modues

php bin/magento module:enable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7} and getting below

```
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot enable Magento_InventoryElasticsearch because it depends on disabled modules:
Magento_Inventory: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventorySales: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventorySales->Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryIndexer: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventorySalesApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventorySales->Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventorySales->Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi: Magento_InventoryElasticsearch->Magento_InventoryIndexer->Magento_InventorySales->Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
```

Please suggest how to enable.